# Split String Into Individual Rows

Tags: sql-server

I'm currently tying to figure out how to split an ID into 2 rows at each instance of '/'. The original IDs will still be saved in the main table as well as temp table 2 but I need the new IDs saved to a new table. All of this happens in temporary tables on a pre-import handler before a report is generated.

The tables output is currently as follows:

```
    RWID     RWLEN      DESCR  QTY  UNIT
  T2/10060  20.0000   SomeInfo  1   pcs
  T2/10061  18.5689   SomeInfo  1   pcs
  T2/10062  20.0000   SomeInfo  1   pcs
```

I need the table to out the following:

```
    RWID    RWLEN     DESCR    QTY  UNIT
  T10060   20.0000  SomeInfo    1   pcs
  T20060   20.0000  SomeInfo    1   pcs
  T10061   18.5689  SomeInfo    1   pcs
  T20061   18.5689  SomeInfo    1   pcs
  T10062   20.0000  SomeInfo    1   pcs
  T20062   20.0000  SomeInfo    1   pcs
```

A snippet of my code is below:

```
-- populate temp table 1 from main table
SELECT *
INTO ##tmp1
FROM main;

-- populate temp table 2 from temp table 1, group and order by RWID
SELECT RWID, MAX(DESCR) as aux
INTO ##tmp2
FROM ##tmp1
group by RWID
ORDER by RWID;

-- populate temp table 3 from temp table 1 then split strings with dividers
SELECT RWID, RWLEN, DESCR, QTY, UNIT
INTO ##tmp3
FROM ##tmp1
UNION ALL
SELECT RWID, NULL RWLEN, NULL DESCR, NULL QTY, NULL UNIT
FROM ##tmp1 
GROUP BY RWID
ORDER BY RWID, DESCR desc;

SELECT 
  RWID = CASE WHEN a.DESCR = b.AUX THEN a.RWID ELSE NULL END,
  RWLEN = CASE WHEN a.DESCR = b.AUX THEN a.RWLEN ELSE NULL END,
  a.DESCR,
  a.QTY,
  a.UNIT

  INTO ##report
  FROM ##tmp3 
  a
  FULL OUTER JOIN ##tmp2
  b on a.RWID = b.RWID;

  SELECT *
  FROM ##report
```

Thanks in advance for your time and assistance.

UPDATE! Thanks so much for all of your help, it really steered me in the right direction. I've figured out how to split the strings shown above as well as the other types of IDs that I'll encounter that I hadn't included in the example. Thanks again for your time and help, you're all awesome!!

Result: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/17a09/1

Comment: is this for mysql or sql-server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a `UNION ALL` like following to get the desired output.

```
SELECT   'T1'+  SUBSTRING(RWID,CHARINDEX('/',RWID)+1,
                         LEN(RWID)- CHARINDEX('/',RWID))  -- + OTHER COLUMN
FROM  [TABLE_NAME]
UNION ALL
SELECT   'T2'+  SUBSTRING(RWID,CHARINDEX('/',RWID)+1,
                         LEN(RWID)- CHARINDEX('/',RWID))  -- + OTHER COLUMN
FROM  [TABLE_NAME]
```

**Complete Example**

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (RWID VARCHAR(30), RWLEN DECIMAL(15,2), 
                   DESCR VARCHAR(50), QTY INT, UNIT VARCHAR(4))

INSERT INTO @TBL
values 
  ('T2/10060',  20.0000   ,'SomeInfo',  1   ,'pcs'),
  ('T2/10061',  18.5689   ,'SomeInfo',  1   ,'pcs'),
  ('T2/10062',  20.0000   ,'SomeInfo',  1   ,'pcs')

SELECT   'T1'+  SUBSTRING(RWID,  CHARINDEX('/',RWID)+1,LEN(RWID)- CHARINDEX('/',RWID)) RWID
          ,RWLEN, DESCR, QTY, UNIT 
FROM  @TBL
UNION ALL
SELECT   'T2'+  SUBSTRING(RWID,  CHARINDEX('/',RWID)+1,LEN(RWID)- CHARINDEX('/',RWID)) RWID
          ,RWLEN, DESCR, QTY, UNIT 
FROM  @TBL
```

**Output**

```
+---------+-------+----------+-----+------+
| RWID    | RWLEN | DESCR    | QTY | UNIT |
+---------+-------+----------+-----+------+
| T110060 | 20.00 | SomeInfo | 1   | pcs  |
+---------+-------+----------+-----+------+
| T110061 | 18.57 | SomeInfo | 1   | pcs  |
+---------+-------+----------+-----+------+
| T110062 | 20.00 | SomeInfo | 1   | pcs  |
+---------+-------+----------+-----+------+
| T210060 | 20.00 | SomeInfo | 1   | pcs  |
+---------+-------+----------+-----+------+
| T210061 | 18.57 | SomeInfo | 1   | pcs  |
+---------+-------+----------+-----+------+
| T210062 | 20.00 | SomeInfo | 1   | pcs  |
+---------+-------+----------+-----+------+
```

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/QGCN20133)</kbd>**

Comment: what if RWID does not start with `T`?

Comment: If that is the case, we ca get the first character using substring instead of hardcoding

Answer (score 0):

SQL-server using CTE

```
declare @table table (rwid varchar(30), rwlen float, descr varchar(50), qty int, unit varchar(4))

insert into @table
values 
  ('T2/10060',  20.0000   ,'SomeInfo',  1   ,'pcs'),
  ('T2/10061',  18.5689   ,'SomeInfo',  1   ,'pcs'),
  ('T2/10062',  20.0000   ,'SomeInfo', 1   ,'pcs')



;with mycte as (
   select *,  cast(right(left(rwid,charindex('/',rwid)-1),1) as int) [num], 1 [start] from @table 
   union all
   select t.*,c.start + 1, c.num from @table t
   inner join mycte  c 
     on c.rwid = t.rwid
     and c.start + 1 <= c.num

)
select
concat(left(rwid,1),  start,replace(rwid,left(rwid,charindex('/',rwid)+1),'')) ,
rwlen,
descr,
qty,
unit
 from mycte  
order by rwid, start
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Cross apply

```
;WITH CTE( RWID, RWLEN,DESCR,QTY, UNIT)
AS
(
SELECT 'T2/10060',20.0000,'SomeInfo',  1,'pcs' UNION ALL
SELECT 'T2/10061',18.5689,'SomeInfo',  1,'pcs' UNION ALL
SELECT 'T2/10062',20.0000,'SomeInfo',  1,'pcs' 
)
SELECT REPLACE(RWID,'2/1',CAST(Rnk AS VARCHAr(2))) AS RWID
        ,RWLEN
        ,DESCR
        ,QTY
        ,UNIT 
FROM
(
SELECT C.*,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY C.RWID ORDER BY C.RWID) AS Rnk
FROM CTE C
CROSS APPLY CTE C2
)dt WHERE Rnk<3
```

Result
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/11626